# Jump to Usage in Android Studio - except for compose previews

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

For my Android/Kotlin app i often write composables like `Header` and previews like `HeaderPreview`.

Later on, i often try jump to a usage of the composable `Header` using the cmd+click shortcut on my Mac.
This will open a dropdown including the preview and other usages.

Is it possible to hide previews from this menu?

---

Dropdown looks like this:

[image]

for the following sample:

```
@Composable
fun HeaderScreen() {
    HeaderSection("Hello there")
}

// find usages of this
@Composable
private fun HeaderSection(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Text(text, modifier)
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun HeaderSectionPreview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    HeaderSection("Hello S.O.")
}
```